# Can I use an emoji as part of a string in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, string

Can I use an emoji in Solidity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an emoji directly in a string literal in Solidity versions [0.6.12](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.12) and earlier. You cannot do so with version [0.7.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.7.0) or later.

Solidity version 0.7.0 updated the parser to disallow non-printable characters in string literals. Instead, they introduced the concept of Unicode string literals, such as `unicode""`, which allows you to use emojis.

#### Examples

**0.7.0 and higher**

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

contract MyContract {
    function myFunction() public {
        string memory myString = unicode"This is an emoji ";
    }   
}
```

**0.6.12 and lower**

```
pragma solidity <=0.6.12;

contract MyContract {
    function myFunction() public {
        string memory myString = "This is an emoji ";
    }   
}
```